# Create Matrix in latex

Tags: latex

Hello, I would like to write a matrix of this form there https://wtf.roflcopter.fr/pics/6NQXLmXa/YC4W9Hu5.jpg with latex but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: This question would be better suited to https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Have a look at the `nicematrix` package

Comment: You may use also the `tabular` environment, even if I am not quite sure if you can insert dashed lines.